How can I use QuestDB with Java 8?
I want to use QuestDB with Java 8, but I can't see any recent releases that include a Java 8 build. I can't upgrade the Java support on my deployment.
Does QuestDB support Java 8 or is this not possible?
If its not supported, is there any workaround I can use?

Whilst Java 8 binaries aren't released for QuestDB, the code is kept Java 8 compatible, so you can build the Maven artifacts yourself. There are some instructions about building QuestDB here.
